# Cypress - How do I wait to select dropdown to load all options?

Tags: automation, cypress

```
cy.get("#severities").then(($optionsArray) => {
           expect($optionsArray.get(0)).to.have.property('childElementCount', 6) 
       let optionVal = new Array()
       optionVal = $optionsArray.children()
       var randomChoice = optionVal[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionVal.length) + 1]
       addAppointment.selectSeverity(randomChoice.text)
       })
```

The `expect` assert will fail because not all options are loaded.

- `expected '<select#severities.form-control>' to have property 'childElementCount' of 7, but got 1`

Is there any way to do it with cypress? if not, then with jQuery?

Comment: The `var` name is not appropriate pls change it. Also pls add information how do you trigger the dropdown so we can help you, your question does not give enough information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for options to load, insert a `.should()` between the `.get()` and the `.then()`. Or perhaps even changing `.then()` to `.should()` will do the trick.

The key thing with `.should()` is that it retires the preceding command until it's criteria succeed, so it's ideal for waiting for async data.

So

```js
cy.get("#severities")
  .should(($optionsArray) => {
     expect($optionsArray.get(0)).to.have.property('childElementCount', 6)
   })
```

will keep re-getting `#severities` and refreshing `$optionsArray` until the `expect()` succeeds, or timeout occurs.

I would separate the part that waits from the part that processes, like this

```js
cy.get("#severities")
  .should($optionsArray => {
     expect($optionsArray.get(0)).to.have.property('childElementCount', 6)
   })
  .then($optionsArray => {
     let optionVal = new Array()
     optionVal = $optionsArray.children()
     var randomChoice = optionVal[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionVal.length) + 1]
     addAppointment.selectSeverity(randomChoice.text)
  });
```

---

For [reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Timeouts)

> **Timeouts**
> .should() will continue to retry its specified assertions until it times out.

```js
cy.get('input', { timeout: 10000 }).should('have.value', '10')
// timeout here will be passed down to the '.should()'
// and it will retry for up to 10 secs


cy.get('input', { timeout: 10000 }).should(($input) => {
  // timeout here will be passed down to the '.should()'
  // unless an assertion throws earlier,
  // ALL of the assertions will retry for up to 10 secs
  expect($input).to.not.be('disabled')
  expect($input).to.not.have.class('error')
  expect($input).to.have.value('US')
})
```

Comment: I totally agree with you, just to clarify, `.then()` tries only once, `.should()` tries the assertions until they pass or until it times out

Comment: Cheers, that was what I aimed to say but maybe it wasn't clear enough.